# Can a computer with ArcGIS Server connect to SQL Express in a different domain?

Tags: arcgis-server, sql-server, deployment, enterprise

As you can see in my diagram, we have ArcGIS set up with 2 other computers for load balancing. We also have SQL Express 2008 but it's under a different domain. My manager's goal was to a) register data on the AGS which is stored in SQLE2008; b) have the other work computers also be able to see the registered data; c) copy data stored in SQLE2008 to the main AGS when publishing (when not registering the data, obviously!)

I know it's all easy enough to do when the SQLE2008 is in the same domain but I'm a bit lost now with these new goals. Is what we're after even possible?

[image: AGS & SQL Express setup]

Comment: Have you considered publishing mapservices from mxds whose featurelayers use database connections to SqlExpress based on DBMS authentication?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just connect to your SQL Server database via IP address instead of computer-name since DNS cannot resolve the name properly. When creating a connection file, set the **Instance** parameter to the IP address of your SQL Server Express.

Another way is to define trust between domains and you can connect to sql server express via domainName\computerName. Lest you forget to consult this with your IT administrator.

Comment: I seem to be getting there. I'm able to connect in ArcMap using the IP address. 

The main AGS seems to be able to connect, but the other two with AGS are having problems with establishing a connection. The error message I got mentions something about older versions of SQL Server client so I'm going to have a look and see what native client or odcb driver it has. Thank you for  your response thus far :).

Comment: This error is not relevant to this question though. However, You need to get the latest SQL Server Express Client and install it on your server.

Comment: Oh, I realize it's not relevant. It's just the next step in trouble shooting! It turns out that whoever installed AGS on these machines forgot to install native clients that will allow it to connect to SQL. 

The good news is that I've also successfully managed to register the data now that I have the native clients on all the computers. I'm in the process of publishing now and it seems to be working. :) Thank you

Comment: Happy to hear that. And please mark the answer per [tour](http://www.gis.stackexchange.com)